# The number of elements of order 3 in $S_7$ is?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

The number of elements of order 3 in $S_7$ is? In $S_7$ there are 2 different disjoint cycles of order 3 i.e (3_)(3_)(1_) and (3_)(1_)(1_)(1_)(1_) but how to calculate no. of elements of order 3 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $\binom{7}{3}\cdot2=70$ three-cycle elements. There are $\binom{7}{3}\cdot2\cdot\binom{4}{3}\cdot2\cdot\frac{1}{2}=280$ elements built of two disjoint three-cycles. Unless I am missing something that would cover all elements of order $3$, so there are $350$ of them.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer at all. Elements of order 3 means how many elements in $S_7$ having $a^3=e$.but I didn't understand why you did $C(7,3)$

Comment: To make an element of order three, it could be a three cycle $(abc)$. What are the $a$, $b$, and $c$? From the seven elements available, you must choose three. Then you must choose which of the two ways they can be ordered into a three-cycle: $(abc)$ or $(acb)$. 

The second part counts how many elements there are that are a product of disjoint three-cycles: $(abc)(def)$. The logic is similar. The $\frac12$ at the end is to recognize that $(abc)(def)=(def)(abc)$.